# Function not returning values

Tags: php, mysql, function

I just asked a question earlier, but now i have formatted it into a function that does not return any value.

This is my code:

```
echo GetHours($UID, $DAY, $MONTH, $YEAR);

function GetHours($UserId, $Day, $Month, $Year){
//filter queries:


    //YEAR:
    if($Year==FALSE){
        $Y = "";
    } else {
        $Y = " AND Year = '$Year'";
    }

    //MONTH:
    if($Month==FALSE){
        $M = "";
    } else {
        $M = " AND Month = '$Month'";
    }

    //DAY:
    if($Day==FALSE){
        $D = "";
    } else {
        $D = " AND Day = '$Day'";
    }

    $Query = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(TotalHrs) 
                          FROM WorkLog 
                          WHERE UserId = '$UserId'$D$M$Y");

    $Data = mysql_fetch_array($Query);

    return $Data;

}
```

Now, i do know that `mysql_` functions are depreciated, but its required for this application at the moment.

My current problem is that this function does not return anything after using GET parameters to test.

Any solutions to this?

**EDIT**

I have changed the last lines to: `return json_encode($Data);` and now the screen shows: `{"0":"8","SUM(TotalHrs)":"8"}`

Comment: Unless it's getting an error, it will always return something.

Comment: `GetHours` returns an array, you can't `echo` an array.

Comment: Try changing '$UserId'$D$M$Y" to '$UserId.$D.$M.$Y'  - I don't think what you have currently is correct. As Barmar pointed out you can't use . in an SQL query, so you will need to put it into a seperate variable first.

Comment: @mfisher91 That will create invalid SQL, you can't use `.` inside the SQL query.

Comment: A bit of sensible code indentation will help us understand what going on even if you dont need it!!!!

Comment: Use `var_dump` instead of `echo`.

Comment: Does this work when using `POST`? Where have you assigned the values? If you output the query is it generated as expected and returns a result?

Comment: What happened to the guy who said the connection wasn't available inside the function.. that's what I thought the issue was but he deleted his answer.

Comment: Ive got an included file, sorry i didnt copy that ... i did some changes and made it return a json encoded data, it now shows this: {"0":"8","SUM(TotalHrs)":"8"}

Answer (score 0):

Always check that `mysql_query()` has not returned an error! Specially if you are building your query from parts generated from inputs that may or may not be present.

This should at least identify any errors in the SQL.

```
function GetHours($UserId, $Day, $Month, $Year){
//filter queries:


    //YEAR:
    if($Year==FALSE){
        $Y = "";
    } else {
        $Y = " AND Year = '$Year'";
    }

    //MONTH:
    if($Month==FALSE){
        $M = "";
    } else {
        $M = " AND Month = '$Month'";
    }

    //DAY:
    if($Day==FALSE){
        $D = "";
    } else {
        $D = " AND Day = '$Day'";
    }

    $Query = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(TotalHrs) 
                          FROM WorkLog 
                          WHERE UserId = '$UserId'$D$M$Y");

    if ( ! $Query ) {
        // just debug code, should be amended for a live site situation
        echo mysql_error();
        return 'Its broken';
    }

    $Data = mysql_fetch_array($Query);

    return $Data;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the data i get returned was an array by doing `echo json_encode(GetHours($UID, $DAY, $MONTH, $YEAR));`

My finished code that works:

```
<?php
include 'assets/db_connect.php';
//Function to get total from WorkLog:


$DAY = $_GET['day'];
$MONTH = $_GET['month'];
$YEAR = $_GET['year'];
$UID = $_GET['id'];


echo GetHours($UID, $DAY, $MONTH, $YEAR);



function GetHours($UserId, $Day, $Month, $Year){
//filter queries:


//YEAR:
if($Year==FALSE){
    $Y = "";
}
else{
    $Y = " AND Year = '$Year'";
}

//MONTH:
if($Month==FALSE){
    $M = "";
}
else{
    $M = " AND Month = '$Month'";
}

//DAY:
if($Day==FALSE){
    $D = "";
}
else{
    $D = " AND Day = '$Day'";
}




$Query = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(TotalHrs) FROM WorkLog WHERE UserId = '$UserId'$D$M$Y");

$Data = mysql_fetch_array($Query);

return $Data['SUM(TotalHrs)'];

}
```